# What should we call our "Chat Room"?

Tags: discusión, chat

Does anyone have name suggestions for Spanish.SE's chat room? I don't like the current name (*Sala de Chat*) because it's too common; I think we should choose a distinctive name for our chat room.

Please feel free to submit **as many good names as you can think up**, even if you personally prefer one of the others.

Comment: Check out the question asked about the Spanish term for chat room too: **[Is there a standard, most common, or most neutral Spanish term for “chat room”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/359/is-there-a-standard-most-common-or-most-neutral-spanish-term-for-chat-room)**

Comment: I'm cycling through these roughly one per day in the order they were proposed just to "try them on". Please drop into the chat room and see how it looks!

Answer (score 12):

I really like the friendliness and sense of intimacy of

#### La tertulia

Comment: I think not only is this perfect, but that we're particularly lucky to have a word in the language so exact for what that chat room is to be used for!

Comment: I just created it : ) [La Tertulia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia).

Answer (score 2):

For completeness let me include the original name of the chat room as supplied by Stack Exchange:

**Spanish Language and Usage**

Comment: I vote for this one for the lame reason that it's easy to remember :P

Answer (score 1):

Having just travelled through the Balkans I think of **ágora** as a Greek word, but reading it here reminded me of one of my favourite Spanish words:

**El Zócalo**

Comment: Is is used only in Mexico?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen it occasionally in Central America though *Plaza principal* was more common there.

Answer (score 1):

I propose

**El rincón de la tertulia**

It expands on Gonzalo Medina's contribution and denotes a sense of place.

Comment: Looks like the votes are not all in so I'm going to take your nice suggestion for a spin on the chat room for a day or so...

Answer (score 0):

How about the translation of the default name into Spanish?

**Lengua española y su utilización**

(Actually it's not so easy to translate literally, so please feel free to submit other variants.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

**El ágora**

[RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=%C3%A1gora) for ágora.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant of a literal translation:

**El idioma castellano y su uso**

Answer (score 0):

A literal one that avoids Spanglish:

**Sala de conversación**

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the previously proposed "Sala de Chat":

**La Sala**

Example of usage:

> Vamos a continuar esta conversación en **La Sala**.

(But I'm not sure I like this better than "La Tertulia," which is quite good.)

Comment: Si bien resulta interesante, sala para mí tiene una connotación demasiado genérica. Puede ser la sala de espera del dentista, la sala de estar donde se ve la tele...

Answer (score -1):

And also let me include the name I temporarily gave the room yesterday based on which seems to be the most common Spanish term to translate "chat room":

**Sala de chat**